# GNOME: I've got problems mounting a WebDAV resource. Where does GVFS's store its error log?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, webdav, gvfs

On Ubuntu 11.10, I've got problems mounting a WebDAV resource (Places > Connect to Server). It doesn't tell me why via the GUI. Other resources work, so I'd like to debug where the error is coming from.

Is there a log GVFS writes to? Or can I switch it into debugging mode somehow?

Comment: CLI's gvfs-mount is equally mute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My WebDAV server requires basic auth over https.

As it seems, GVFS GUI and gvfs-mount do not properly pass credentials to WebDAV servers. I need to dig further to find out if that is only for certain methods or a real bug in gvfs.

And obviously, 401 responses (forbidden/auth required) from a peer server, are reported as "server did not answer" erroneously by GVFS GUI and gvfs-mount.

Answer (score 1):

It probably just outputs it to stderr. Look in `~/.xsession-errors`.

Comment: Nope. Nothing in there. The GVFS mounter GUI just returns after 5 minutes or so with an error saying the resource did not answer, could not be contacted due to DBUS security and such.